# Draw deadlock graph(using functions) and added ability for scaling

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts. I need to draw deadlock graph like in jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/1wksg5jn/263/ and added ability for scalling.
Instead of this:

```
ren.label('Server process id: 2<br/>Server batch Id:2<br/>Execution context:<br/>Deadlock', 440, 120)
    .attr({
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'black',
        padding: 20,
        r: 80
    })
    .add()
    .shadow(true);

ren.label('Key lock: 1', 240, 70)
    .attr {
        r: 2,
        width: 105,
        height: 70,
        fill: 'lightgray'
    })
.add();
```

I want to draw deadlock graph elements using functions with something like this:

```
function DrawEllipse(label, positionX, positionY) {
    .attr({
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'black',
        padding: 20,
        r: 80
    }).add();
}

function DrawKeyLockTable(label, positionX, positionY) {
    .attr({
        r: 2,
        width: 105,
        height: 70,
        fill: 'lightgray'
    }).add();
}
```

and call this functions in my code.

Comment: It would probably be good if you actually ask a question. What are you asking specifically? What part of implementing what you need are you struggling with? Maybe say what you have tried, etc. The more information and context you give the easier it is for others to answer.

Comment: My apologize... I want to draw a deadlock graph like this in example https://jsfiddle.net/1wksg5jn/263/ , but how I can create and call functions for drawing arrows, ellipses, key lock tables and separators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create functions to draw SVG elements in this way:

```
function drawEllipse(label, positionX, positionY) {
    ren.label(label, positionX, positionY).attr({
        r: 80,
        padding: 20,
        width: 105,
        height: 70,
        fill: 'lightgray'
    }).add();
}

function drawKeyLockTable(label, positionX, positionY) {
    ren.label(label, positionX, positionY).attr({
        r: 2,
        width: 105,
        height: 70,
        fill: 'lightgray'
    }).add();
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7sympovh/

Comment: This works in the way I need it.
I have an additional question, how can I do a scaling of the graph by x and y axis?
My jsfiddle example look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/7sympovh/61/

Comment: You would have to make the size of the elements dependent on the axis units. https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels